# Is there a list of examples of orthogonal spectra?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, examples, stable-homotopy, stable-homotopy-category

Schwede's [symmetric spectra book project](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~schwede/SymSpec-v3.pdf) provides point-set models of many important spectra as symmetric spectra, including (in §I.1) the sphere spectrum, Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectra, several Thom spectra, and $\mathit{ku}$ and (in §I.3) endomorphism ring spectra, matrix ring spectra, group ring spectra, and algebraic $K$-theory.

Is there an analogous reference for examples constructed as orthogonal spectra? I'm hoping to use them to better grasp the concept of orthogonal spectra and how to manipulate them.

So far, the best reference I've found has been Schwede's notes again: the constructions of $\mathit{MO}$ and $\mathit{ku}$ pass through orthogonal spectra, and I should be able to adapt this to some other situations. [May-Quinn-Ray](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/e_infty.pdf) also discuss Thom spectra as orthogonal spectra (under the name $\mathscr I^*$-prefunctors).

Comment: Schwede's notes on equivariant homotopy theory use orthogonal spectra, and you might find some more examples there (just remove the $G$).